# Imported a virtual harddisk as new device and I need it to export it same way (VirtualBox)

Tags: export, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualhost

My first experience with vms. I got a folder with vmdk files (and lots of other stuff too) was able to make it work through using this under  New>Use a existing harddisk.
I have made some changes within this and need to send it to another pc. But when I send the same folder -the one mentioned above- to the other pc it seems like there hasnt been any changes. 
There is another folder within the Virtual VM folder in a different place but that is just too small for this case (everything should be around 16 gb this folder is just over 1gb)
How can I export this the same way as I got it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same settings when you move your VM from VirtualBox to another computer, you need to export your VM from VirtualBox.

You can do this, Select your VM **File >> Export Appliance** and import VM on another machine **File >> Import Appliance**. The extension of file will be .OVA.